# OverflowError while RandomizedSearchCV in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am trying to optimize my DecisionTreeRegressor in Scikit-Learn using RandomizedSearchCV. As there are too many possible combinations to search for, i get the following error:

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

One solution i found is to reduce the number of possible parameters in the param distribution so there is a smaller number of combinations to search for. I could split it up and run several randomized searches and put it all together afterwards. But I'd like to keep it simple and have it all in one search.

```
# Creating Pipelines

nom_cat_columns = ['Bezirk', 'Ortsteil', 'Wohnungstyp', 'Objektzustand']
ord_cat_columns = ['Qualität']
num_columns = ['Baujahr', 'Stockwerk', 'Anzahl_Stockwerke', 'Modernisierung', 'Wohnfläche']

nom_cat_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('nom_cat_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
                                   ('ohe', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore',
                                                        drop = 'first'))])

ord_cat_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('ordenc', OrdinalEncoder(categories = [['Einfache Qualität', 'Normale Qualität',
                                                                            'Gehobene Qualität', 'Luxus']], 
                                                handle_unknown = 'use_encoded_value',
                                               unknown_value=np.nan)),
                                 ('ord_cat_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean', fill_value = 1))])


bj_pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('num_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')),
                                 ('custscal', custom_scaler(strategy = 'noscaling'))
                                ])

sw_pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('num_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')),
                                 ('custscal', custom_scaler(strategy = 'noscaling'))
                                ])

an_sw_pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('num_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')),
                                 ('custscal', custom_scaler(strategy = 'noscaling'))
                                ])

mod_pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('num_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')),
                                 ('custscal', custom_scaler(strategy = 'noscaling'))
                                ])

wf_pipeline = Pipeline(steps = [('num_imp', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median')),
                                 ('custscal', custom_scaler(strategy = 'noscaling'))
                                ])

# Creating ColumnTransformer for Preprocessing

transformers = [
    ('nom_cat', nom_cat_pipeline, nom_cat_columns),
    ('ord_cat', ord_cat_pipeline, ord_cat_columns),
    ('bj', bj_pipeline, ['Baujahr']),
    ('sw', sw_pipeline, ['Stockwerk']),
    ('an_sw', an_sw_pipeline, ['Anzahl_Stockwerke']),
    ('mod', mod_pipeline, ['Modernisierung']),
    ('wf', wf_pipeline, ['Wohnfläche'])
]

prep = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers, remainder='passthrough', sparse_threshold=0, n_jobs = -1)

# Creating final pipe

dtr_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("prep", prep),
    ("dtr", DecisionTreeRegressor())])

# Search Parameters

scal_strat = [
                'noscaling',
                'standard',
                'minmax',
                'maxabs'
            ]

imp_strat = [
                'mean',
                'median'
            ]

param_distributions = [{
                'prep__ord_cat__ord_cat_imp__strategy': [
                                                               'mean',
                                                               'constant'
                                                               ],
                ### SCALING ###
                'prep__bj__custscal__strategy': scal_strat,
                'prep__sw__custscal__strategy': scal_strat,
                'prep__an_sw__custscal__strategy': scal_strat,
                'prep__mod__custscal__strategy': scal_strat,
                'prep__wf__custscal__strategy': scal_strat,

                ### IMPUTATION ###
                'prep__bj__num_imp__strategy' : imp_strat,
                'prep__sw__num_imp__strategy' : imp_strat,
                'prep__an_sw__num_imp__strategy' : imp_strat,
                'prep__mod__num_imp__strategy' : imp_strat,
                'prep__wf__num_imp__strategy' : imp_strat,

                ### MODEL HYPERPARAMETERS ###
                'dtr__criterion' : [#'squared_error', 
                                    'absolute_error', 
                                    #'friedman_mse', 
                                    #'poisson'
                                    ],
                'dtr__splitter' : [
                                    'best', 
                                    'random'],
                #'dtr__max_features' : [i for i in range (79,80)],
                'dtr__max_depth' : [i for i in range (3,50)],
                'dtr__min_samples_split' : [i for i in range (15,50)],
                'dtr__min_samples_leaf' : [i for i in range (1,35)]        
              }]

# Creating RandomizedSearchCV

random = RandomizedSearchCV(dtr_pipe,
                            param_distributions, 
                            random_state=42, 
                            cv = 5, 
                            scoring = {'mape' : make_scorer(mean_absolute_percentage_error, greater_is_better=False)},
                            refit = 'mape',
                            return_train_score = True,
                            n_iter = 100,
                            n_jobs = -1
                            )
# Fitting RandomizedSearch

random.fit(X,y);
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback.  Ideally, provide a minimal reproducible example (here, a dataset).

Answer (score 1):

So the basic problem is that you specify too many parameters with too many values to tune. I get it, brute-forcing avoids having to ask yourself all kinds of questions. However, parameter tuning really only has to happen for variables where you can't know what the right value is.

Think about the choice of median vs mean imputation, if your distribution is heavily skewed, then probably you want to use median, is it more or less normally distributed, then you can use mean. This is why we do exploratory data analysis!

To give a more concrete answer to how to solve your problem, I see two main ways to tackle this:

1. Reduce the number of possible values your grid search is using for tuning, for example, for 'dtr__max_depth' use steps of 5 instead of 1 to reduce number of possible values. Just your last three parameters have 55930 combinations (if my math is correct).
2. Use a library like [`hyperopt`](http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/). Hyperopt uses algorithms to determine your optimal parameter space, this makes it less exact but much faster for large parameter spaces. This is probably your best option as your parameter space is *way* too big.